# Want to play the drums

Tags: drums

After thinking about for a long time ive made my choice and am serious about wanting to play the drums.  My problem is I have no experience with drums whatsoever. I want to know what should i know about drums before buying a set. And what kind should i buy to learn to play the drums. Is there any specific things i have to buy or any things i have to becareful with? What would be the best set for a beginner who wants to learn to play? My budget is about 300 to 400 at the most. I want a set so i can learn to play? Does the quality matter if you want to learn to play? I just need some tips on what to buy basically and if theres any treatment i have to do to my drumset like replacing parts or something like that. Keep in minf i know absolutely NOTHING about drums so please dont use terms a beginner wouldnt know or atleast explain the term. I want to play to stuff like heavy metal indie rock alternative rock if that even matters...

Comment: 300 or 400 what ??

Comment: Well, yes, I'd agree with the question being duplicate for a simple reason - if you are a beginner then you certainly want to start with a real drumset. But to answer the second part of you question - you could also get an electronic set or just a set of practice pads in order to practice at home. But since you're a beginner, that would be counter-productive for your habits in the long run.